# Missing icon styles for Vanilla LibreOffice after update

Tags: libreoffice

As title says, my installation of LibO (from "Collabora" -- the one in the Mac Appstore) is now missing several icon sets with the recent upgrade. Info:

- Version: 5.2.1.1
- Build ID: 4afc24bb8402fb220914e41da1503f86441578cb
- CPU Threads: 4; OS Version: Mac OS X 10.10.5; UI Render: default;
- Locale: en-US (en.UTF-8); Calc: group
- machine is MacBook, early 2015, 10.10.5 Yosemite

What I see:

[image: libo on osx]

But this is what I have for my 5.2.1.2 installation on Ubuntu:

[image: libo on ubuntu]

Prior to the latest upgrade, the icon sets were the same on both installations. Any help on how to get the missing icon sets?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just got the update to this version of LibO:

- Version: 5.2.1.4
- Build ID: e145cf15d1b452e575867b990095d176cf53383c

At least my *preferred* icon styles have been restored in an "artwork" fix to this release ("Breeze" and "Sifr"). Still, the only further one this "Vanilla" AppStore version of LibO includes is the "Tango" set, unlike the larger set of options I see on my Ubuntu setup.

It would still be good to know how to add icon sets to the OSX LibO installation, but at least the icons are now bearable again.